# Can I mix a fixed left offset with a relative width in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a situation like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                              |
|                      +---------------------------------------------------+   |
|                      |                                                   |   |
| <-  fixed width  ->  | <-                flexible width               -> |   |
|                      |                                                   |   |
|                      +---------------------------------------------------+   |
|                                                                              |
| <-                         flexible width                                 -> |
|                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What this is supposed to represent is an outer DIV and its child (also a DIV) appearing in the browser. The outer div takes up, say, 90% of the viewable area `(width: 90%)`. If the screen is resized it will resize. It's OK for it to have a minimum width.

The child div is meant to stay a fixed number of pixel from the left of the outer DIV `(left: 200px)`.

I would like it to resize with its parent (i.e. childWidth = (parentWidth - 200) * .9).

Is it possible to do this with CSS / how?

Comment: +1 for the ascii skillz.

Comment: Thanks, @iambriansreed -- I used to make ASCII art on my dad's ATEX -- miss those days. I got fancy and made an example on jsfiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/benf1977/kLjTt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just add `right: 0px` to the inner div in addition to `left`.

(also, try jsfiddle.net instead of ascii ;))

Comment: Do I need to set a width? Just setting left and right, right seems to be ignored and the width is the full size of the outer. Does it matter that my outer div is fixed position? Didn't think it'd be relevant.

Comment: Also, yeah, I'll try to jsfiddle this. Good suggestion! =)

Comment: Ah, OK. inner must be `position: absolute` and not `position: relative`. Thanks!